# How Could I transform XML into XSL without getting error, using JAVA xml API

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd

I tried to convert XML file into HTML using XSLT format but i got an error

```
RROR:  'Namespace prefix 'vuln' is undeclared.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
```

The XML file started with

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" version ="2.0" href="nvdXSLT.xsl"?>
<nvd xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" 
 xmlns:scapcore="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" 
 xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" 
 xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" 
 xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" >
   <entry id="CVE-2007-5333">
   <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
     <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apache_software_foundation:tomcat:4.1.34</vuln:product>
     <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apache_software_foundation:tomcat:4.1.37</vuln:product>
     <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apache:tomcat:4.1.24</vuln:product>
     <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apache:tomcat:5.5.5</vuln:product>
     <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apache:tomcat:5.5.2</vuln:product>
   </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
   <vuln:cve-id>CVE-2007-5333</vuln:cve-id>
   <vuln:published-datetime>2008-02-11T20:00:00.000-05:00</vuln:published-datetime>
   <vuln:last-modified-datetime>2014-03-15T23:16:41.310-04:00</vuln:last-modified-datetime>
  </entry>
 </nvd>
```

And i created XSL transformer to transform the xml content into organized format and display the output on html format javax.xml.transform API.
The XSL file as follow:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"           
   xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" 
   xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1"
   xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Parsing NVD XML file</h1>
    <table border="1">
              <tr>
                 <th>hasAffectedProducts</th>       
              </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="nvd/entry">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:for-each select="/vuln:vulnerable-software-list"><xsl:value-of select="vuln:product" /></xsl:for-each></td>
                 </tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="vuln:cve-id" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="vuln:published-datetime" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="vuln:last-modified-datetime"/></td>
         .....
```

The JAVA API that I used to do transformation

```
  public void transform(String dataXML, String inputXSL, String outputHTML)
        throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
    StreamSource in = new StreamSource(dataXML);
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outputHTML);
    transformer.transform(in, out);
    System.out.println("The generated HTML file is:" + outputHTML);

}
```

Simply, received XML file and XSL file and create output file int HTML format.

Comment: Your input XML is not namespace-well-formed as it uses the `vuln` prefix without declaring it.  XSLT can only operate on namespace-well-formed XML so you need to get the XML fixed at source to declare its namespaces properly.

Comment: It fixed, but i got empty table, it seems XSL transformer doesn't work properly, any help please ?!

Comment: The transformer is working correctly, it's the stylesheet that is wrong ;-)

Comment: For future questions, please try to include examples that are truly representative of your real problem.  If you're not sure whether or not a particular feature might be significant then it's better to include it anyway - it's much easier for us to filter out noise than to guess what might have been left out.

Comment: I totally agree BUT the current problem "empty output" comes out after solving the first one "namespace error". So, based on that i come up with updates on my original post to be adjusted with questions that i have been asked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with your stylesheet.

The first issue involves the namespaces.  You need to bind the `vuln` prefix to the same namespace URI in the stylesheet as it is in the document, and you also need to bind a prefix to the `http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0` URI which is the default namespace of your document.  Unprefixed names in XPath expressions refer to elements that are not in a namespace, so to match elements in a document with a default `xmlns` you must use a prefix in the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4"
     xmlns:feed="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0">
```

You should also *remove* the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0"` from the stylesheet as this will put the output elements in this namespace rather than treating them as HTML.

With these namespace bindings in place you can correct the outer `for-each` to look for elements in the right namespace

```
<xsl:for-each select="feed:nvd/feed:entry">
```

The second problem is in the inner `for-each`

```
 <xsl:for-each select="feed:nvd/feed:entry">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:for-each select="/vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
```

where you're using an absolute path where you should be using a relative one - you're trying to `for-each` over all the `vulnerable-software-list` elements at the *root* level of your document and print their respective first `product` child.  The transformer is correctly giving you an empty node set as the root element is actually called `nvd` and is in a different namespace.

If instead you want to `for-each` over *all* the `product` elements in the current entry then change it to

```
<xsl:for-each select="vuln:vulnerable-software-list/vuln:product">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: appreciated your help, the problem still same thing, empty out put !!, I added some lines to the XML file to give you the complete picture of the problem. I hope you got what I mean. !!

Comment: @user3247440 You say you're using the `javax.xml.transform` API - can you edit the question to show the Java code you're using to run the transformation?

Comment: @user3247440 I notice you've just added `xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0"` to the stylesheet - where does that come from?  Does your real input XML have a default namespace declaration (unlike the example input you've posted in the question where the `nvd` and `entry` elements are not in a namespace)?

Comment: I took that link for the XML file style-sheet tag !! just to make sure all URIs are the same between the two files

Comment: @user3247440 that makes _all_ the difference - if your input document has an `xmlns` default namespace then you can't use unprefixed names in your XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is very clear as to why it can't compile the stylesheet:

```
ERROR:  'Namespace prefix 'vuln' is undeclared.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
```

`vuln` is a namespace you need to be declared in the root of the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:vuln="http://www.someurl.com/vuln">
```

I think you want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Parsing NVD XML file</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>hasAffectedProducts</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/nvd/entry">
                        <xsl:for-each select="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="vuln:product"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="vuln:cve-id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="vuln:published-datetime"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="vuln:last-modified-datetime"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works BUT the problem I couldn't make the XSL read correctly from XML. I just got the heads of the table with out the results of rows. Pleas any help !!

Comment: Any help to figure out this problem !! I just got empty table without records, it seems the XSL file does not work properly !!

Comment: It works for me. Update your post with the latest xslt.

Comment: I updated the xslt file to be more detailed and the problem still exist. Thank you very much !!